# how to use RegEx.Replace or search string in HTML string using Linq

Tags: c#, html, regex, string, linq

i want to provide search facility to user. I have html data as string in database. I am using Linq to SQL. But I don't want to search string in the HTML tags. Hence I want to strip the HTML tags from the string I have.

How can I do that?

I know Regex needed is `Regex.Replace(inf.EmailSubject, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);`

and I do the reading part as below:

```
from s in dc.UserLandingPages 
where !s.UserProductDetail.IsDeleted
&& (s.Nickname.Contains(strSearch)
|| s.Headline.Contains(strSearch)
|| s.SubheadLine.Contains(strSearch)
|| s.HTMLData.Contains(strSearch))
select new UserLandingPageResult { _userLandingPage = s };
```

How can I use regex in the contains part?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Regex.IsMatch` that does a pattern matching.

```
string text = "noname001";
string pattern = @"[nN]ame"; // either Name or name
bool status = Regex.IsMatch(text, pattern);
```

Comment: that's fine. But how do I use this inside the query I provided above?

Comment: @PratikGaikwad `if(status)` or `if(Regex.IsMatch(text, pattern))`